# Does Count realize a IEnumerable

Tags: c#, .net, ienumerable

Just a quick question.

Does a count realize a IEnumerable? say you have a method yielding, by how I understood it the method is at a stand still until its enumerated, but a count should need to enumerate it to get the count?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes. The source for an `IEnumerable` `.Count` is:

```
    public static int Count<TSource>(this IEnumerable<TSource> source) {
        if (source == null) throw Error.ArgumentNull("source");
        ICollection<TSource> collectionoft = source as ICollection<TSource>;
        if (collectionoft != null) return collectionoft.Count;
        ICollection collection = source as ICollection;
        if (collection != null) return collection.Count;
        int count = 0;
        using (IEnumerator<TSource> e = source.GetEnumerator()) {
            checked {
                while (e.MoveNext()) count++;
            }
        }
        return count;
    }
```

([source](https://github.com/Microsoft/referencesource/blob/master/System.Core/System/Linq/Enumerable.cs))

If the `IEnumerable` is actually castable to an `ICollection` which has a "magic" way of counting, then it would use that instead of iterating.

Comment: Does that mean i can use it instead of ToList?

Comment: and it makes count alittlebit scary :P

Comment: Most collections you use day to day implement ICollection and therefor have a faster way of getting the count. But it is always good to be aware that Linq extensions like *Count()* just *try* to find a fast way and if there is none, you may end up iterating the whole thing.

Comment: @KaiBrummund Yes I knew this about most collections, it was just a freak thought on ienumeration and yield that led me to the thought of, ohh crap count could potentially be extreemely expensive.

Comment: Depends what you're using it for really. :-)